# nginxをプロキシとして使う方法

Tags: nginx

nginxをプロキシとして使う際の設定で困っています。
現状1の構成のものを2のようにしたい場合、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

1. 今現在の構成
   クライアント -> nginx -> proxy -> インターネット

nginx.confからincludeしてる設定ファイル

```
upstream proxy_server {
  server 54.248.71.136:3009;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://proxy_server;
    proxy_set_header x_custom_header_hoge "hogehoge";
  }
}
```

2.こうしたい
クライアント -> nginx -> インターネット

この場合、nginxの設定をどのように変えればよいのでしょうか？

nginxはヘッダーを追加するためのプロキシという位置づけで、クライアントで明示的に指定予定です。
単純にヘッダーを追加する処理だけさせて、本来のリクエスト先にリクエストさせたいのですが、
proxy_passでプロキシ先を指定しないと行けない感じになっていて、どうしたらよいのかなと。
(リバースプロキシとして使う予定はないです)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ちなみに、Squidをプロキシとして使う案も検討はしたいですが、まずはnginxで検討したいです。ヘッダーの書き換えを動的に行いたく、nginxのほうがそれが実現できやすいと感じています。Squidに関してではなくて、Nginxで2を実現させる方法のアドバイスをいただきたいです

Comment: 「nginx フォワードプロキシ」で検索すると設定例が見つかると思いますが、何か問題があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header x_custom_header_hoge "hogehoge";
    }
}
```

`resolver 8.8.8.8` の部分はお使いの環境に合わせてDNSサーバーのIPを設定してください。